# How to create a cron job using cron to grep some file

Tags: cron

Does crontab have an argument for creating cron jobs using `grep` command to extract some data from text ?

this my command :

```
clog /var/log/messages.log | /usr/bin/grep -a user1 >> access.txt
```

when i execute this command ; the file text access.txt will be created with the content i need

in cron job , the file will be created without content

Comment: did you try to add full path to `clog` and to access.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the full path to `clog` and `access.txt` to be sure what you run and where you write.

Example cron record:

```
5 10 * * * /usr/local/sbin/clog /var/log/messages.log | /usr/bin/grep -a user1 >> /path/to/access.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

solution : `/usr/local/sbin/clog /var/log/messages.log | /usr/bin/grep -a user1 >> pull/path/of/file`